# Why can't I use intValue() in autocomplete?

Tags: android

As you can see in the picture below, `intvalue()` and also `tostring` don’t appear. If I type them manually, they are impossible to resolve. I’ve cleaned the project, reopened it, but nothing seems to resolve the problem. Anybody has an idea what’s wrong? `currentTemp` is a double.

[image: <code>intvalue()</code> doesn’t appear]

Comment: what type is "currentTemp"?

Comment: post that relevant code

Comment: `double` or `Double`?

Comment: Oh, I saw now. It's double with lower "d". My bad guys, sorry for post this question.

Comment: If you are using `double` then do this way `(int)cuurentTemp` and if you are using `Double` then use this `currentTemp.intValue()`.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. Always add the code to your question, instead of a image of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've used `double` which is a so called "[Primitive Data Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)"

Change the dataType of `currentTemp` to `Double` (with a capital D) and `.intValue()` should become available.